# SQLAlchemy Migrating from ORM to Core

Tags: sqlalchemy

When we originally built our app, we were using SQLAlchemy ORM, but as time goes on, we're getting more and more frustrated with its intricacies and overhead and want to move to something faster and more explicit in making queries performant. In some early tests, it looks like Core hits those needs, so we'd like to start making the switch.

All of our current models are defined using Declarative for example:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    autocomplete_crosses = relationship(u'Parent')

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = Column(ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    users = relationship(User')
```

Is there an easier way of using these with declarative aside from needing to call `__table__` every time. Here's what I'm currently doing, which feels verbose and ugly:

```
s = select([User.__table__.c.name, Parent.__table__.c.name])\
    .select_from(User.__table__.join(Parent.__table__))
```

Can I access my table names directly and just use those to make this cleaner?

Comment: Well, there's nothing stopping you from doing `user = User.__table__`.

Comment: Any way to do that automatically for all tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to do it automatically for all tables, you can reflect it after you've defined all your classes:

```
for cls in Base._decl_class_registry.values():
    if hasattr(cls, "__table__") and cls.__table__ is not None:
        globals()[cls.__table__.name] = cls.__table__
```

I don't recommend actually doing this because it's very magical. In particular, it breaks linters because it modifies `globals()`, but this is how you would do it.